# Expanding a contour in python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Using `cv2`, I am able to find the contours of text in an image. I would like to remove said text and replace it with the average pixel of the surrounding area.

However, the contours are just a bit smaller than I would like, resulting in a blurred edge where one can barely tell what the original text was: [image: image with blurred edges]

I once chanced upon a `cv2` tutorial with a stylized "j" as the sample image. It showed how to "expand" a contour in a manner similar to adding a positive sample next to every pre-existing positive sample in a mask.

If such a method does not already exist in `cv2`, how may I do this manually?

Comment: I think that dilation is the effect you recall from your tutorial.

Comment: @the_cheff thank you! Can I approve this as the answer, or should I just close the question?

Comment: You can answer your own question

Answer (score 2):

The function I sought was dilation, as detailed here:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('j.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```